# How do I filter a pandas dataframe by ID's that don't or do occur after a time period

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, filter, pandas-groupby

I have pandas Dataframe example trying to create filter data frames by IDS that do not occur after a time period

also if possible I know I'm asking too much, DF with an additional column by grouped IDS with true or false which did or did not occur

```
     ID      timestamp
0    x1      2015/09/27 09:10:30
1    x2      2015/10/11 05:10:30
2    x2      2015/12/20 11:10:30
3    x1      2015/11/17 01:10:30
4    x3      2015/09/09 17:10:30
5    x4      2015/09/25 06:10:30
6    x5      2015/09/23 15:10:30
7    x1      2015/12/21 11:10:30
8    x5      2015/09/27 08:10:30
```

need to get a DF that's filtered by ID categories that occurred again after 30 days

also, create a boolean(true or false) or (0,1) array as additional column 
for ID's that churned or no longer occurred in a group method or with case statement if that's how it is done

Comment: Can you share a sample of the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You could use logical indexing and set operations i.e:

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
ids = set(df.ids.unique())
recent_ids = df.loc[df.timestamp > timestamp,'ID']
not_seen = ids.difference(set(recent_ids))
```

This will select all ids which have been seen in the last 30 days and provide the difference between that set and the set of all ids ever seen.

Comment: getting this also is there a way to set the date instead of datetime.now()
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: You need to cast the timestamp column in your dataframe to a datetime look up the pandas documentation `to_datetime()`. You can set the datetime you want to compare to, take a look at the python datetime documentation.

Comment: thanks however it seems recent_ids gives you a array without index as its just unique values easier way to get that would be to just do right join if null merge